# Edit - Go to not working. VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Trying to call:

`Edit - Go to File`

`Edit - Go to member`

`Edit - Go to symbol`

They do not work at all :)

`Edit - Go to All` works good so far.

Looks like it become unworkable since I've logged into my Microsoft account from VS. (Already tried to log out or similar - no success).

Since I'm trying to make a habit to work without resharper this bug is a pain for me. (Resharper has been deleted before this bug happened)

What could be the issue?

Comment: Given the absence of any information - no idea. It works on my machine. You don't even mention the *version* you are running. RTM, Update 1, Update 2, Update 3?

Comment: After some time of the googling it I've found out that the version and the machine specific stuff doesn't impact.  That's why I've just decided to post more common information to collect as much feedback as possible.  @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: If it doesn't, then why does this work on my and my colleagues machines? Besides how do you expect help when you don't provide *any* information? Have you tried **repairing** your installation? Have you installed any updates? What do you even mean by `do not work at all`, the dialog box doesn't show? The wrong tab is sellected? It's the **same** dialog as `Go to All`. If you type f it will switch to `Go To File`.

Comment: Does `do no work at all` mean it doesn't find any files, or that it's slow when you type the characters one by one? Or that it doesn't find anything if you type an entire filename at once?

Comment: FYI the lates update for Visual Studio 2017 is 15.3.3, released this week. You'll find the IDE's version in `Help > About`